# Foreignobject from SVG is not converted and appear in PDF by TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, d3.js, svg, tcpdf

I am converting my svg to pdf using TCPDF php library. My svg are having foreignObject with body, div and span for displaying some comments in text.
When I open that SVG in browser its look fine, but when I converting it to PDF by using TCPDF I am getting empty space where my text should appear along with that getting gray background too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `<foreignObject>` in your SVG, then you would need a converter that not only renders SVG, but also renders HTML.  Perhaps someone markets an SVG converter that supports HTML, but I am not aware of one.

The SVG standard provides the `<foreignObject>` element so that users may embed non-SVG content in an SVG. The SVG standard does not require an SVG render to support any specific types of content that might be placed in the foreignObject.

The fact that browsers support HTML in a foreignObject is obviously purely as a consequence of them being HTML viewers.

There is no clear and obvious workaround other than avoiding the use of foreignObject.

If you don't care that the SVG content stay as vectors when converting to a PDF, then you could use something like phantomjs to convert the SVG to a bitmap. Then turn that bitmap into a PDF.  That's not a very nice solution though.

Comment: I am not facing any issue in Brower, its working fine with browser's., But when I am using that SVG in TCPDF then foreignObject elements are not appearing. And yes, I need SVG to stay in vector form. I am using $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/tux.svg', $x=30, $y=100, $w='', $h=100, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false); for adding svg in PDF from TCPDF

Comment: Good luck finding an SVG to PDF converter that supports HTML.  You may have to seriously consider changing your SVGs so that they don't use `<foreignObject>`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau please look at how "draw.io" work. They definitely use foreignObject in svg for displaying text. And then convert this svg to pdf using some server side converter. What converter do they use??

Comment: @krispo It looks to me like draw.io has it's own internal XML-based file format. It has exporters for SVG and for PDF. But it doesn't seem like it converts directly from SVG to PDF.